# Why are my Facebook conversion tracking pixel values incorrect?

Tags: facebook, tracking, shopify, ads

I'm using Facebook's Conversion tracking pixel on Shopify's checkout page to measure ROI for ad sales, but I'm getting wildly inflated sales numbers.

The tracking code as given by Facebook is below:

```
    <!-- Facebook Conversion Code for Checkout -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var fb_param = {};
fb_param.pixel_id = 'myID';
fb_param.value = '0.00';
fb_param.currency = 'USD';
(function(){
  var fpw = document.createElement('script');
  fpw.async = true;
  fpw.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fp.js';
  var ref = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  ref.parentNode.insertBefore(fpw, ref);
})();
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" alt="" style="display:none" src="https://www.facebook.com/offsite_event.php?id=myID&amp;value=0&amp;currency=USD" /></noscript>
```

The code I added to the checkout page in Shopify is below.  I set the value, but otherwise it's the same.  The value-setting variable is known to be working for GA tracking.

```
<!-- Facebook Conversion Code for Checkout -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var fb_param = {};
fb_param.pixel_id = 'myID';
fb_param.value = '{{ total_price }}';
fb_param.currency = 'USD';
(function(){
var fpw = document.createElement('script');
fpw.async = true;
fpw.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fp.js';
var ref = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
ref.parentNode.insertBefore(fpw, ref);
})();
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" alt="" style="display:none" src="https://www.facebook.com/offsite_event.php?id=myID&amp;value=0.01&amp;currency=USD" /></noscript>
```

Not sure why I'm getting very large numbers like 6487.00, when single-transaction sales rarely exceed 1000.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is better suited to http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same issue and tried this one and it seems to work:

```
{{ total_price | money_without_currency }}
```

as long as the `fb_param.currency = 'USD';`

is still there it will show you the right currency in Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the units expected by facebook was dollars but sent was the number of cents.  I divided total_price by 100 and that resolved the issue.